# Two projects | Two log files

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Project1 is using classes from project2 and project3.

Project 2 and project 3 has seperate **log4j.properties** file and logging classes (Pro2.java & Pro3.java with info,debug methods) in their src folder.

Project1 has a main method that calls

```
    Pro2.logInfo("This is a log for project2");
    Pro3.logInfo("This is a log for project3");
```

I want these logs to be logged in **two seperate log** files as I set in their log4j.properties file.

Comment: You can define a new [appender](http://www.vaannila.com/log4j/log4j-file-appender-example-1.html) for each logger. Additionally, I think you need only one log4j.properties.

Comment: Can I do so with two log4j.properties in two projects?

Comment: Yeah, but you need 'two' projects within your IDE; not only two classes

Comment: yes there can be more than two projects and same is the case will all that projects. i.e each project will have its log4j.properties file and when its class run logs. That log should go in seperate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log4j will automatically look for and use config files it finds on the classpath. It looks for files called log4j.properties and **log4j.properties** and possibly others.

Alternatively you can programatically load config using;

```
String filename = "/path/to/config/Project1log4j.properties";
PropertyConfigurator.configure(filename);
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can only have one active log4j.properties file (there are exceptions in J2EE environments).

what you want to do, is configure the logging for both projects in a single properties file. You'd need to define two appenders, and specify the categories for each project to use their own appender.

Comment: Yes one way is to make another appender but can I do so with two log4j.properties in two projects?

Comment: It works in a J2EE environment by having multiple instances of log4j so that they can initialize independently. You'd have to have some custom classloading going on to isolate the log4j instances. Is there any reason why you can't simply merge the properties files?

Comment: One reason for having seperate lo4j.properties file is project requirement. As you know eclipse is a plugin base. We can add/remove plugin so each plugin can have seperate log file to read its logs. I think you are clearer now? Please make your this point more clearer "You'd have to have some custom classloading going on to isolate the log4j instances".

Comment: Are you developing eclipse plugins? If that's the case, you may already have some classloader isolation. If each plugin has a private copy of log4j it *might* work. The way log4j is designed is that it has one configuration. The only way around that is to get separate copies of it loaded in separate classloaders. Getting that working correctly (with the rest of your code being able to talk to each other) is complicated and would require far more information about your project.

Comment: No I am not developing eclipse plugins but a kind of application that uses plugins and we can increase/decrease number of plugins. So basically I am developing plugins not for eclipse.